# Mapbox Gl JS resize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm facing an issue on resizing map when I have a lot of element/markers to load on it. The resize seems to be blocked and the map having that kind of view:
[image]

Here is how the map is called:

```
map.on('load', () => {

            // const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
            var group = [];
            map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(
                { showCompass: false }
            ));

            // Refresh map info on : Zoom
            map.on('zoomend', (e) => {
                // Launch the action only on human zoom not an automatic zoom (teh zoom of the beginning)
                if (typeof e.originalEvent !== 'undefined') {
                    refreshSearchResultOnMapAct(map);
                }
            });

            // Refresh map info on : Drag
            map.on('dragend', () => {
                refreshSearchResultOnMapAct(map);
            });

            // Add markers to the map.
            for (const marker of geojson.features) {
                // Create a DOM button for each marker.
                const button = document.createElement('button');
                // Button style depending on type_estate.
                if (marker.properties.type === 'habitation') {
                    button.className = 'btn map__price';
                    button.prepend(marker.properties.price);
                } else {
                    // IE style.
                    button.className = 'btn map__point';
                }

                // Action for markers click
                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                        data: {
                            action: 'show_modal_map_item',
                            id: marker.properties.id_estate,
                        }
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        $('.js-map-card').html(response.data);
                        $('.js-map-card-wrapper').removeClass('is-hidden')

                        $(document).on('click', '.js-map-card__close', function () {
                            $('.js-map-card').html();
                            $('.js-map-card-wrapper').addClass('is-hidden')
                        });
                    })
                });

                group.push(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                // Add markers to the map.
                let map_points = new mapboxgl.Marker(button)
                    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                    .addTo(map);

                // Push the map markers(map_points) inside markers array
                markers.push(map_points);
            }
            // Zoom on markers
            var bounds = group.reduce(function (bounds, coord) {
                return bounds.extend(coord);
            }, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(group[0], group[0]));

            map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 20 });
            map.resize();
        });
```

It is in a function after an ajax success. Which one is triggered when user is submitting a search form.
Each marker come from an elastic search result providing geolocalisation points.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
// Refresh map info on : Drag
map.on('dragend', () => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    refreshSearchResultOnMapAct(map)
  }, 0);
});
```

To offer Mapbox some processor capacity to update the map and afterwards (0 ms but putting it at the end of the UI processing queue) place the newly received markers from the api response.

Comment: Thanks,

unfortunately, it does'nt solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try different timeout settings (100ms, 1000ms for example) just to know if the order of event handling is the issue?

Comment: Yes,
But i finally found the issue. I put a setTimeout on the function that get the search results and create the map.
The problem didn't came from the dragend that populate with map elements.

When I have too many result, the Elastic Search script was longer than the mapbox one, so the map.resize function was call too early, when the div didn't exist yet.

Thanks for your help anyway.